# Writing regular expression that will filter entered username

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regexp that will filter any username which:

- Starts with number or letter *(not case sensitive)*
- Can include `-` but cannot contain more than one in a row

  *example* `u-s-e-r`✔ `us-er`✔ `us--er`✖
- Also username cannot start with `-` or end with `-`

  *example* `-user`✖ `user-`✖
- It also needs to be at least 1 character (*letter or number*) and max 39.

The closest I've come to my result is something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-(?=[a-zA-Z\d])){0,38}
```

This matches exactly what it should match, but it also matches some things that it shouldn't.

Basically these **shouldn't** be valid:

```
-username
_username_
__us_ername
us_er
username-
1user--name
132uname-
-uname1234
-username-
user--name
av34axc-
1234567890A1234567890B1234567890C1234567890D
```

And these **should** be valid:

```
Username
a-a
aBc
BaC
1-1
1-2-3-4
q-1-2-3
q-q-q-q-q
username
123username123
username3123
1234
user-name
13-13
q1-q2-q3
a
A
1234567890A1234567890B1234567890C123456
1234567890A123456-7890B1234567890C12345
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{1,39}$)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySE2BV/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D.%7B1%2C39%7D%24)%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cd%5D%2B(%3F%3A-%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cd%5D%2B)*%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{1,39}$)` - the length must be 1 to 39 chars
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much this works flawlessly, do you have any books/e-books/tutorials on regex that could help me.

Comment: @neca I can suggest doing all basic lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. And certainly, follow SO regex tag, try to answer regex questions here and never give up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative look ahead to implement the hyphen restrictions:

[`^(?!.*-(-|$)|-)[a-z\d-]{1,39}$`](https://regex101.com/r/6o0UEq/1/)

Comment: Updated link. Thanks for letting me know!